# How can I detect errors (bleeps) in MP3s?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, sound-editing

How could I automatically detect MP3 file errors that result in bleeps?

In [this example MP3](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42351200/cut.mp3) I can hear bleep at 0:02.

Comment: Are you trying to rip a CD accurately or just checking some existing MP3's?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Checking existing mp3s, OS Win7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) - it has a module called *File Integrity Verifier* that can spot obvious problems. When I run this check on your example file, it indicates that the file length is incorrect which would indicate an encoding problem. To do the check, open the file in Foobar (via **File->Open**) then right-click it in the playlist and choose **Utilities->Verify Integrity**. It may not always be able to detect errors though.

There are some other programs like [MP3Val](http://mp3val.sourceforge.net/), [MP3Utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/MP3Utility.shtml) and [MP3 Check](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3check/) that do a similar thing to foobar2000's integrity verifier, but again, I'm pretty sure that they can only detect obvious errors.

Comment: Original file is available at this location: http://soundcloud.com/mashedandconfused/im-finally-horny-mousse-t-vs/download
Bleep can be heard at 0:46

After running integrity verification Foobar2000 found only length related problems.

Comment: @c97: It will only ever give fairly generic errors like that because it does not know how the error will actually affect the sound that you perceive. On a properly encoded file you will not get any errors. I just wanted to check that the error was not being caused by the file being re-saved incorrectly. If you have a load of files and you know that more of them are faulty, I suggest you try testing them all in one go to see if it can detect the faulty ones. It is possible to import folders into Foobar2000 and test multiple files at once.

Comment: I thought so, but what if file is reencoded from faulty mp3? This validation tool should point some obvious hearable errors. I'm looking for that kind of program.

Comment: @c97: I think that the error might be carried forward if it is re-encoded but it would probably depend on the exact encoder. But if the error is compensated for then I don't think it is realistically possible to detect. For instance, some music tracks feature white noise, periods of silence, deliberate distortion etc. that could be difficult to distinguish from genuinely corrupted audio.

Answer (score 0):

[MP3 Shield](http://download.cnet.com/MP3-Shield/3000-2170_4-47270.html) is long discontinued and not fool-proof, but it can detect fakes and several types of corruption including pops, loops, and silence. It is however prone to the occasional false-positive and false-negative (it used to be possible to [submit](http://web.archive.org/web/20051103181500/http://www.mp3shield.com/) incorrectly detected files to update the algorithm, but unfortunately there are no more updates).

[image]

Comment: Well it didn't detect bleep in the example file nor in the original ( http://soundcloud.com/mashedandconfused/im-finally-horny-mousse-t-vs/download )